# Entity Framework Interfaces

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, interface, ienumerable

So, I am working on a project dealing with a game.  I have three projects right now, Web, Data, Data.EF.  I would like the Web to not know anything about the concrete classes in Data.EF, but instead only reference the Interfaces in Data.  The problem I am running into is that I have two classes Dungeon and AvailableDay.  AvailableDay has two important members.  Weekday which is a `DayOfWeek` and `IEnumerable<IDungeon> Dungeons` which is a "list" of dungeons that are available that day.  The issue I am having is that I keep getting this error:

> The navigation property 'Dungeons' is not a declared property on type 'AvailableDay'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

My AvailableDay mapping class is:

```
internal class AvailableDayMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<AvailableDay>
{
    public AvailableDayMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("AvailableDays", "dbo");
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);
        this.HasKey(t => t.DungeonID);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Dungeons).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.DungeonID);
        this.Property(t => t.Weekday);
    }
}
```

AvailableDay class:

```
public class AvailableDay : IAvailableDay
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int DungeonID { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<IDungeon> Dungeons { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek Weekday { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to query it by:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IAvailableDay>> GetAvailableDaysAsync()
{
    return await _Context.AvailableDays
                .Include(t => t.Dungeons)
                .GroupBy(t => t.Weekday).SelectMany(t => t).ToListAsync();
}
```

How can I pull in a list of Dungeon data while only allowing the Web to access it through interfaces?

Comment: try using the syntax _Context.AvailableDays.Include("Dungeons").GroupBy... Not saying your way is wrong I've just never seen that way of including.

Comment: @Tim `using System.Data.Entity` lets you call [`Include()` with a property expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for pointing that out.  Never done it that way before.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN: Requirements for Creating POCO Proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx):

> A navigation property that represents the "many" end of a relationship **must return a type that implements ICollection**, where T is the type of the object at the other end of the relationship.
>   "

So change the property type:

```
public virtual Collection<Dungeon> Dungeons { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried both Collection and ICollection, but still get the same error.

Comment: @ScubaSteve it has to be the model type, so `Dungeon`. If you don't want to expose the entity types, you'll have to (auto)map them to your Data models.

Comment: by (auto)map, do you mean IoC in my Web project?

Comment: @ScubaSteve see [Mapping two classes easily in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444936/mapping-two-classes-easily-in-c-sharp).